# Is there any way to call a method from uitabbaritem and not load a uiviewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `tabBarController` which holds three viewcontrollers,and I want to add another `UITabbarItem` to the `tabBarController` which calls an `alertView` to display. The `tabBarController` is on storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Try Following Steps :

1. Add UITabBarItem to UITabBar.
2. Disable added UITabBarItem.
3. Add UIButton which same size of UITabBarItem to UITabBar.
4. Add target and selector which display alert view

Answer (score 1):

No.  **You can only add view controllers to a tab bar**.
You could add a blank view controller that on `viewWillAppear:` would display the alert and then *set the active tab to one of the others*.  I wouldn't recommend it. It's ugly and a very bad user experience.